# Default Constructor not called while creating object in Java

Tags: java, string, constructor, static, default-constructor

```
public class StaticFinalExample {
    static String str;

    public void StaticFinalExample() {
        System.out.println("In Constr");
        str = "H";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticFinalExample t = new StaticFinalExample();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

In above example the output is null.

Why was not the constructor called?

Comment: it is called, but the method you have there isn't, because it isn't  a constructor. remove the void keyword, and try again. the 'void' is the returntype, constructors have none

Comment: @Stultuske yes you are right. I did a mistake here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Constructors don't have a return type. There shouldn't be `void` in your StaticFinalExample() method, if that's your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using class name as a method name, it's ambiguous. When we notice any name having same value as class, our mind reads as a class name not as actual usage (method name in your case).

It's not a good practice. It does not mean you can not use method name as class name, but you should avoid using same name.